# How authentic is salat ul hajah?

Tags: salat, dua

I have read a hadith about salat ul hajah or prayer of need which says pray two rakat after ablution and then making a particular Dua. But the grade of the hadith is daif. My question is, is there any more hadith more reliable to indicate about salat ul hajah? Also should daif hadith be acted upon? Also there is a sahih hadith about a blind man asking the prophet(saw) to make Dua for him and the prophet(saw) taught him a certain dua, can it be considered as prayer of need as well?

Answer (score -1):

**Not Authenticated (Muhammed didn't say it)**

> حديثُ صلاةِ الحاجةِ فإنَّ فيه يا محمدُ أتشفَّعُ بك إلى اللهِ 
>   [الإنصاف في حقيقة الأولياء] 
>   **فيه مقال** => means an argument about it

And this is not correct due asking Mohamed You should ask God not a person

**Muslim faith is to worship God not the prophet**

But if you want something pray God , raise your hand and call him with his best names .